# How to print for once (no multiple) if status change?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a code to read analog data and I print it out like digital (ON, OFF). When the status ON, I see multiple ON on the screen; also when it's OFF, I see multiple OFF on the screen. After reading I will transmit data to the Google Spreadsheets. So I just need to transfer when the status change. I rode some topics here but I did not find what I want exactly. If I find a solution I think it'd be helpful for people.

Here is my code:

```
 while True:
  if sensor > 1.60:
   Status = 'ON'
  else:
   Status = 'OFF'

  print("Status : {}".format(Status))
```

I tried *break* command below *Status = 'ON'* but it was not a good solution.

Comment: Is this code executed in some kind of loop? If you are only interested in a change of status, you will have to keep track of the previous value and base your logic on it.

Comment: Unless you show the loop containing the print, we won't be able to explain how to print outside the loop...

Comment: Initialize `prev_Status` to `None`.  Then, after updating `Status`, compare it to `prev_Status`.  If it's the same, do nothing.  If it's not, then print `Status`, and do `prev_Status = Status`.

Comment: @DisplayName There is `while True:` at the top of the code for loop.

Comment: @TomKarzes I tried to write what you mean but I think I had some problems to write it. Can you explain by code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include all the relevant code.

Comment: Ok, as you requested I posted what I was talking about.  It's similar to what others posted, except I explicitly showed the initialization and the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested, here's what I was suggesting.  It's very similar to what others have posted, except here I've explicitly shown the initialization and the loop.  The only thing missing is the code that updates `sensor`.

```
prev_Status = None

while True:
    if sensor > 1.60:
        Status = 'ON'
    else:
        Status = 'OFF'

    if Status != prev_Status:
        print("Status : {}".format(Status))
        prev_Status = Status
```

Answer (score 1):

try this maybe? you need to initialize preStatus = 'ON' at the beginning

```
if sensor > 1.60:
   Status = 'ON'
else:
   Status = 'OFF'

if preStatus!=Status:
   print("Status : {}".format(Status))
   preStatus=Status
```

Comment: You forgot to indent the last assignment.  It serves no purpose if the `if` condition is false.

Comment: my understanding of the problem is that nothing gets printed if the condition is false, in which case preStatus==Status

Comment: Um, yeah, that was my point.  It's generally bad coding to do a useless assignment.  The assignment is useless if they're *already* equal.  You only need to do the assignment if they are *not* equal.  In other words, you forgot to indent the last assignment, just as I said.  It's not a functional change.  It's just better (more efficient) code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another variable that is updated and referenced every time the input is checked.

```
if sensor > 1.60 and previous_status == 'OFF:
  Status = 'ON'
  previous_status = 'ON'
elif sensor <= 1.60 and previous_status == 'ON':
  Status = 'OFF'
  previous_status = 'OFF'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you don't compare `Status` and `previous_Status`

Comment: @CoşkunKozakbaş. I changed my answer to show a better relation between the two.